# Gaussian Quadrature in Python

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np

import scipy.integrate as integrate

def f(x):
    return np.sin(x)

def gauss(f,0,2,5):
    val,error = integrate.quadrature(f,a,b, maxiter = n)
    print("Integration value is: ", val)
    print("Error is: ", error)
```

Above is my code. I keep getting the syntax error below. Can someone help me resolve this issue?

```
   def gauss(f,0,2,5):

               ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: No offense, but you should probably go over [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). This is some very basic language syntax error. You can't have numbers in the definition of a function's arguments... You can, though, define default values: `def gauss(f, a=0, b=2, n=5):` (which I have a strong feeling it's what you were going for...)

Answer (score 0):

You put constants in function definition. This is not allowed - you should have variable names there.

Constants could be passed only to function call.

Comment: Constants can also define default values

Comment: @Tomerikoo you're right, but I did not want to make simple answer too difficult.

Comment: I don't think it's *too difficult*... On the other hand it might be a bit misleading to tell a beginner that *Constants could be passed only to function call*. What happens when he sees default values for the first? Then it will be difficult for him...

Comment: @Tomerikoo why don't you post your answer and I delete mine then?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

f = lambda x: np.sin(x)

def gauss(f,a,b, MaxOrder):
    val,error = integrate.quadrature(f,a,b, maxiter = MaxOrder)
    print("Integration value is: ", val)
    print("Error is: ", error)
    
print(gauss(f, 0, 2, 5))
```

Hope this works!